# function return content as string from a require

Tags: php

Is there a way I can return the require as a string?

The view_users contains an HTML and PHP code and it is likely being parse then I want to return the parse version of it as a string.

Class Users

```
class Users{ 

    public function viewUsers(){  
               $userData;
           require  $path."view_users.php"; 
    }

}
```

***index.php***

```
include_once(dpath. "/users.php");  
$users= new Users();

function wrap_contents($content = ""){
    echo'<div class="wrap">';
    echo $content;
    echo '</div>';
}


wrap_contents($users->viewUsers());
```

Comment: What do you mean "return the function"?

Comment: just updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get any php output as a string, Use the ob_* function family.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php

```
ob_start(); // blocks output and store it in a buffer instead
require  $path."view_users.php"; 
$output = ob_get_contents(); // get buffer contents into a variable
ob_end_clean();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class Users{ 

    public function viewUsers(){ 
           ob_start();
           $userData;
           require  $path."view_users.php"; 
           return ob_get_clean();
    }

}
```